# Require field keep asking to enter the value even after entered in Salesforce Macro

Tags: console, sales-cloud

I am trying to create a Macro in Salesforce Sales Console. After enter the Macro name and click on Save, record is not created, instead value get cleared from the Macro name field and show the message as `Complete this field` !. I have logged in as Admin profile. Any advise? Thank you in Advance.
@Derek F is this image help you?
[image]

Comment: I think you'll need to [edit] your question to include more details.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution myself, there are many tabs of Opportunity and Leads opening in the console, after closing all the tabs, I was able to Save Successfully. It could be some other reason, I am not sure.